# How to extract specifics frames from mp4 file using C# metro application

Tags: c#, windows-8, frame, mpeg-4, applicationwindow

I didn't find a way to extract specifics frames (ex: frame 1, 2 and 13) from a mpg4 file in a windows 8 application metro style. I found how to extact frame and directly save it in a file 
using C++.
I have to only use C# to extract frames in BitmapImage object to show it in a Image.
Any one could help me please?

Comment: Update your C++ project to a Managed C++ (CLI) class library and then you can consume the resulting assembly in any .NET compliant language.